# Glassfish taking 20s to do hot deployment, is that right?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, glassfish, glassfish-3

I'm working in a `JSF` project with `Eclipse` and `Glassfish 3.1.2`.
Every time I did a minor change and save it, Glassfish do the `hot deployment`, but is taking too much time to do that, about `20s`, at least.

Can I do something do deacrease this time ? Is horrible develop something where you have to wait all time time everytime I change something.

**UPDATE**
This is how my project settings.

[image]

Just open the folder below, this surprise me, is this so many .jar files, is this correct ?

[image]

And this one:

[image]

My Glassfish configuration :

[image]
Any idea ?

Comment: Same to me, when java file is edited and saved, i have to wait about 20s. Now, i use Tomcat, Tomcat take about 3s.

Comment: Are you serious ? 3 seconds only ?

Comment: yes, i'm using Tomcat 7.  3 seconds only !

Comment: GF hotdeploy performance decreases when you've an EAR instead of WAR. With WAR, it deploys in a subsecond. There was previously also an issue related to this: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17094. Further I've also seen complaints that GF hotdeploy performance decreases when Maven is used. For EARs I'm using JRebel.

Comment: @BalusC, do you know how change Glassfish to use WAR then instead EAR ? I Googled about JRebel, but is very expensive, I would used only for me, did you have to paid for it ?

Comment: Use WAR project instead of EAR project (thus... EJBs inside WAR). For JRebel, I'm using company's license.

Comment: @BalusC, I mean, how do I do this change about EAR`s to WAR in my project ?

Comment: I was reading and a EAR deployment is only necessary when EJB is used, right ? So to use a WAR project I would have to change my project to not use EJB anymore ? Man, what annoying thing..

Comment: @RongNK, but how do you change EJB connections then ?

Comment: Since EJB 3.1 ("Java EE Web Profile") you can just use EJB in WAR.

Comment: @BalusC, I never heard about EAR before, could you please help me out in do this change ? I update my post showing my project settings. I really don't understand you're last answer. I'm reading about it, but none place are explaining how to change from EAR to WAR project.

Comment: You don't have an EAR project. So your hotdeploy slowup is caused elsewhere.

Comment: Should I do what about it then ? Did you need something of my project ?

Comment: @BalusC, I notice so many .jar files inside of my project, is this correct ?

Comment: I really need help with this thing..

Comment: after many hours I notice that the problem is with the `WEB-INF\lib` folder, with many `.jar`, but isn't  there where they should be ?

Comment: Please I need help with this, my project development speed is being slow 'cause of this..

Comment: Glassfish contains many jars by default, which is no problem for your performance. Nor are the jars in your project.

Comment: @Aquillo, so what you think is causing my slowdown then ?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to deploy a `GlassFish` application. To speed up development/debuging we need a way to instantly deploy web applications. One of the ways is to use hot deployment feature, another lesser known feature is ‘directory deployment’. You simply point `GlassFish` to your development directory and let it pick up and deploy application from there. No packaging and re-deoploying hassles. The catch is whenever you want to re-deploy your application you just need to `touch` a file called `.reload` which should be present in your web folder.
Following is the command and directory structure you can use.

```
–|myproj
–|–|src
–|–|web
–|–|–|WEB-INF
–|–|–|–lib
–|–|–|–classes
–|–|–|–web.xml
–|–|.reload
```

`GLASS_FISH_HOME/bin/asadmin deploydir full_path_to_you_web_folder`