# Glassfish: Fast hot deployment setup

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, web-deployment, development-environment

What is a good setup for really fast hot deployment of a Java EE application to Glassfish, so the changes are visible in less than e.g. 1 second?

Currently I'm using Eclipse Luna to develop a JSF2.1 application on Glassfish 3.1.2. When I change something in a jsf, a managed bean or an ejb, it takes ages to deploy the changes. I've already found some good advise,

- [GlassFish (real) hot deployment of JSF pages and resources (CSS etc.) in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19332931/2621521)
- [Glassfish taking 20s to do hot deployment, is that right?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16913469/2621521)

but I don't think I can speed up my setting to get the deployment under e.g. < 1sec. Also I think "directory deployment" is not supported in GF3.

**So what setup can you recommend? Should I switch to Netbeans? Or are there any hidden Eclipse settings to speed this up? Or do you reach fast hot deployments with Eclipse Luna and I'm just missing some properties?**

Some more information: I have to use GF3.1.2 Furthermore I use maven, the backend jar and the front end war are bundle together in an ear file. I use EJBs and JPA to connect to a DB2 database. So except GF nothing special.

Comment: Ok, I've switched off the automatic build (menu Project), turned on immedate publishing in the server settings. This seems to deploy at least the jsf changes (as described). Nevertheless bean changes, still need a full publish. But I'm still investigating. Maybe one of the free JRebel alternatives can help (http://javainformed.blogspot.de/2014/01/jrebel-free-alternative.html)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Glassfish does not support hot deployment. You would need something like JRebel to accomplish that. In case you're not bound to glassfish you might consider switching to wildfly or some other AS that supports this feature.